# server error (500 internal server Error) when searching a word with accent

Tags: search, internal-server-error

Hi I have a french website in which when i search a french word, i have:

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)

I searched every where but i dont find how to resolve it .
can anyone help me with this?

to be more clear, my website uses cms Ezpublish , 
installed on linux Debian 7.

In my search page: /content/search when i seach a word with accent i have this internal error, 
in my logs i dont receive any error, (in url i have: /content/search?SearchText=donné)
when i search without accent , i have no problem. everythings fine.

the accent in url of other pages, in browser are whitout accent = Société > Societe

i have another ezpublish site on one another server and search works perfectly so i am sure its a problem with server.
I think problem comes from virtual host cause i dont have it when i search with ip adresse of website.

> VirtualHost *:80 >
>         Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>           AllowOverride All
>
> ```
>   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>         RewriteEngine On
>         RewriteBase /
>         RewriteRule ^api/ index_rest.php [L]
>         RewriteRule ^index_rest\.php - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)?content/treemenu.* index_treemenu\.php [L]
>         RewriteRule ^var/([^/]+/)?storage/images(-versioned)?/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^var/([^/]+/)?cache/(texttoimage|public)/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^design/[^/]+/(stylesheets|images|javascript)/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^share/icons/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^extension/[^/]+/design/[^/]+/(stylesheets|flash|images|lib|javascripts?)/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^packages/styles/.+/(stylesheets|images|javascript)/[^/]+/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^packages/styles/.+/thumbnail/.* - [L]
>         RewriteRule ^var/storage/packages/.* - [L]
>             RewriteRule ^/favicon\.ico - [L]
>             RewriteRule ^/design/standard/images/favicon\.ico - [L]
>                 RewriteRule ^/css/.*\.css - [L]
>                 RewriteRule ^/js/.*\.js - [L]
>         RewriteRule .* index\.php
>                 RewriteRule ^/api/[^/]+/v1/ /index_rest.php [L]
>             RewriteRule ^/bundles/ - [L]
> ```

```
    </IfModule>
```

I also added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
and in my charset in conf.d i uncommented this line.
nothing's changed!

Answer (score 1):

500 is a server side error code . You'd better give more detail about the error for example the error log.The cause of the error may be various.

I consulted [the documentation of EZ for virtual host setup](http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.4/Installation/Virtual-host-setup).That may be some kind of help.And after you modify the configuration of apache,a restart may be needed.